# How to store excel data in database using PHP MySQL for any number of column?

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to store excel data into database. Right now, i can store data for specific number of columns. Like, i wrote the following code to store data where there are two columns:

```
require 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$input_file_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$excel_data = array();
$input_file_type = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($input_file_name);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($input_file_type);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($input_file_name);
$worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
$highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestDataRow();
$highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);

for($row = 1; $row <=$highestRow; $row++){

    if($row > 1){
        $rowData = $worksheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, True, False);
        $rowData[0][0] = date("Y-m-d", PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue()));
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `data_test`(data_date, data_value) VALUES('".$rowData[0][0]."', '".$rowData[0][1]."') ";

        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
            echo "Success <br>";
        }else{  echo mysqli_error()."<br>"; }
    }


}
```

My first column will always be a date type.

But, in reality, before uploading file i can't know how many columns are there.
For this, how can i store data of any number of columns where the first column will always be date type ?

Can Anyone help with an example ?